# Android: ProgressBar and textual information about the progress

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am writing an application which downloads data and updates a database at the beginning. As this takes quite a while, I want to show the user a progress bar and some textual information about what is done at the moment.

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    public static int count = 0;
    public static File path; 

    private ProgressBar myProgressBar;
    private int myProgress = 0;
    private TextView textView; 


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myProgressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_progress);
        new Thread(progressBarThread).start();
```

...
... updating the data
...

```
        Intent showList = new Intent(this, ListFragmentActivity.class);
        startActivity(showList); 

    }

    private Runnable progressBarThread = new Runnable(){

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (myProgress<100){
                try{
                    myHandle.sendMessage(myHandle.obtainMessage());
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch(Throwable t){ }
            }
        }

        Handler myHandle = new Handler(){

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //
                myProgressBar.setProgress(myProgress);
            }
        };
    };
}
```

I tried to set manually the progress, by using e.g. myProgress=60; and textView.setText("Die Datenbank wird aktualisiert.");

Unfortunately no ProgressBar and no textual information is displayed.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Use AsyncTask, it's much better for progressbars

Comment: where your showing the progressBar. you can use AsyncTask instead of Handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this for your progress bar, execute it by `new ProgressBarAsync().execute();`

```
public class ProgressBarAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... counter) {
        while (myProgress<100){
            try{
                publishProgress(myProgress);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                myProgress++;
            }
            catch(Throwable t){ }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        myProgressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have now 2 async tasks (1 for the progressBar and one for the update of my database). Do I have to take care of the concurrency of the 2 tasks?

Comment: Can you put the in one AsyncTask